# Connection to cosmosdb fails in runtime when wrapped in a function

Tags: c#, azure-cosmosdb

I get this runtime error when I wrap connecting to CosmosDB in af function.

"Microsoft.Azure.Cosmos.CosmosObjectDisposedException: 'Cannot access a disposed 'CosmosClient'. Follow best practices and use the CosmosClient as a singleton."

It works fine if its not inside a function.

Why is that?

This is my function:

```
    public static async Task<Container> connectToCosmosAsync()
    {
        // New instance of CosmosClient class
        using CosmosClient client = new(
            accountEndpoint: "https://xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx/",
            authKeyOrResourceToken: "=xxxxxxxxxxxxx="
        );

        // Database reference with creation if it does not already exist
        Database database = await client.CreateDatabaseIfNotExistsAsync(
            id: "uniconta"
        );

        Console.WriteLine($"New database:\t{database.Id}");

        // Container reference with creation if it does not alredy exist
        Container container = await database.CreateContainerIfNotExistsAsync(
            id: "uniconta",
            partitionKeyPath: "/id",
            throughput: 400
        );

        Console.WriteLine($"New container:\t{container.Id}");

        return container;
    }
```

Comment: Probably a good idea to read credentials from a file rather than pasting directly in your code, so that you don't accidently leak your credentials to the internet.

Comment: Also: you should really regenerate your keys immediately. Even though you've edited them out of your question, anyone with enough rep can view revision history.

Answer (score 0):

By `using CosmosClient client = ...` you dispose of the client as soon as it leaves the scope (the method boundary in this case). If you run the code in a single method, it works because the client has not been disposed yet as all the code is in the same scope.

As soon as you move the creation of client, database and container to a separate method, the client is disposed as the end of the method, hence the error.

There are several ways to solve this (besides not moving the container creation to a separate method:

### Inject the code that uses the client in a function

```
public static async Task connectToCosmosAsync(Function<Container, Task> useContainer)
{
    // New instance of CosmosClient class
    using CosmosClient client = new(
        accountEndpoint: "https://xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx/",
        authKeyOrResourceToken: "=xxxxxxxxxxxxx="
    );

    // Database reference with creation if it does not already exist
    Database database = await client.CreateDatabaseIfNotExistsAsync(
        id: "uniconta"
    );

    Console.WriteLine($"New database:\t{database.Id}");

    // Container reference with creation if it does not alredy exist
    Container container = await database.CreateContainerIfNotExistsAsync(
        id: "uniconta",
        partitionKeyPath: "/id",
        throughput: 400
    );

    Console.WriteLine($"New container:\t{container.Id}");

    // Use container
    await useContainer(container);
}
```

Instead of creating a container and using it, you can call the function like this:

```
await MyClass.connectToCosmosAsync(async (container) => {
  await container.DoSomething();
  await container.DoSomethingElse();
  // ...
};
```

Using this approach, the client is not disposed yet when you use the container. After the function has been called, the client is disposed.

### Promote the client to a class level variable

```
internal class MyClass : IDisposable
{
  private readonly CosmosClient _client;

  public MyClass()
  {
    _client = new(
            accountEndpoint: "https://xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx/",
            authKeyOrResourceToken: "=xxxxxxxxxxxxx="
        );
  }

  // Simple implementation of IDisposable
  public void Dispose()
  {
    _client.Dispose();
  }

  public async Task<Container> connectToCosmosAsync()
  {
        // Database reference with creation if it does not already exist
        Database database = await _client.CreateDatabaseIfNotExistsAsync(
            id: "uniconta"
        );

        Console.WriteLine($"New database:\t{database.Id}");

        // Container reference with creation if it does not alredy exist
        Container container = await database.CreateContainerIfNotExistsAsync(
            id: "uniconta",
            partitionKeyPath: "/id",
            throughput: 400
        );

        Console.WriteLine($"New container:\t{container.Id}");

        return container;
  }
}
```

Please note that the above is only a sample. It shows that the class itself implements `IDisposable` in order to dispose of the client when it is disposed.

If you use a dependency injection container, you can register the class as a singleton e.g.:

```
services.AddSingleton<MyClass>();
```

The DI container will make sure that dispose is called at the end of the object lifecycle.

You can either inject the instance as required or use the service provider to get the instance:

```
var myClass = serviceProvider.GetRequiredService<MyClass>();
await myClass.connectToCosmosAsync();
// use container
```

If you only need a single container, you can also move the container creation into the constructor.